# Why was Joab concerned about taking a census

Tags: david, samuel, joab

I’ve read many commentaries on 2 Samuel 24:3 that debate several reasons why the census was sinful but none of them address Joab’s reason for asking.  Joab was a gifted military commander and loyal to David, but he was not a moral man.  He killed Abner, Uriah, and Amasa, none of them for military advance but for various and questionable reasons.  His concerns seem directed toward military or personal gain, and I see nothing to indicate humility.  With no indication of him acknowledging God for much of anything, why would he now be concerned about offending God.  My question is not, what was the offense, but what would generate Joab’s concern.  Once that question is satisfied, the context of the verse might become clear.

Answer (score 1):

Joab believed in God's power. He was not an idol worshiper.

> 2 Samuel 2:27
> Joab answered, "As surely as **God lives**, if you had not spoken, the men would have continued pursuing them until morning."

> 2 Samuel 10:11 Joab said, “If the Arameans are too strong for me, then you are to come to my rescue; but if the Ammonites are too strong for you, then I will come to rescue you. 12Be strong, and let us fight bravely for our people and the cities of **our God**. **The Lord** will do what is good in his sight.”

Uriah respected him.

> 2 Samuel 11:11 **Uriah** said to David, "The ark and Israel and Judah are staying in tents, and **my commander Joab** and my lord's men are camped in the open country. How could I go to my house to eat and drink and make love to my wife? As surely as you live, I will not do such a thing!"

Joab is a complex character.

Comment: Not buying it Tony.  Just because someone uses a little God talk doesn't mean he's a believer.  Actions speak louder than words.   He did bad things with no sign of repentance, as did David.  I don't see anything in his life that would make me put stock in him as a man of God.  As for Uriah (who he murdered), he respected him as a military commander.  If it had been Uriah speaking about spiritual issues I would have no questions.  No, Joab was not a man to concern himself with spiritual affairs.  Something is missing here.

Comment: I've made modification.

Comment: But that's my point.  I don't think he worshiped anything but himself.

Comment: You could be right.

Comment: Thanks for your input Tony.  It's a tough question.

Comment: Well Tony, it seems you were more right than I.  I've been told that I'm trying to keep everything black and white, and that is not the case here.  I think Joab's commitment was nowhere as dedicated as David's, and that he had serious flaws, but still had a foundation in faith.  Thanks again Tony.

Comment: You're welcome. We are here to help each other out.